# Defining a function using a preceding expression

Tags: functions

How can I automatically define a function inside my Mathematica code using a result (expression) that preceded the point of definition.

For example:

```
tt = x + y
x + y     

f[x_, y_] := 2*tt     

f[1, 1]
2 (x + y)
```

doesn't give $f$ as 2($x+y$) with $x$ and $y$ being variables here. So, instead of giving `f[1,1]=2(1+1)=4` it gave `2(x+y)` not recognizing that $x$ and $y$ are meant to be variables.

How can I define $f$ here so that it picks up its definition from the expression of $tt$ automatically, with $x$ and $y$ as variables?

The reason I need this is that it would save me manually copying and pasting the expression `x+y` into the function defintion, and would make my code run automatically even when `tt` gives different expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to use `=` instead of `:=`

```
tt = x + y
f[x_, y_] = 2*tt
f[1, 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
f[x, 4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
f[x, y]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Great. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`f[x_, y_] := Evaluate[2*tt]` would also work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Clear f;
f[u_, v_] := 2*tt /. {x -> u, y -> v} 

f[1, 1]
(*4*)

f[x,y]
(*2 (x + y)*)
```

Comment: Yes, it works. Many thanks. It is a bit inconvenient that Mathematica doesn't have a simpler way to automatically detect these as variables, don't you think?

Comment: if you look at f[x_, y_] := 2*x tt; f[2, 1] // Trace you will see that tt is not evaluated until the arguments of f is passed to the left hand side. that is the nature of functions in MMA.